# Replacing the keys of a dictionary with values of another dictionary to create a new dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to replace the keys in the `ages` dictionary with the values (the names) of the `d1` dictionary (as per below).

I want the final dictionary to look something like: `[Callum: 20, Herrara, 21 etc]` instead of just have the last value `[Liz: 19]` which I am currently getting.

Here is my code

```
d1 = {
0 : "Callum",
1: "Herrera",
2: "Bob",
3: "Bill",
4: "Liz",}

ages= {
0: 20,
1: 21,
2: 40,
3: 20,
4: 19,}

for v in d1.values():
    A=v

for v in ages.values():
    B= v

dictionary3= {
    A:B,
}

print (dictionary3)
```

Comment: Use a *dictionary comprehension*.

Comment: `for v in ages.values()` iterates over the whole dictionary.

Comment: Fix your indentation - currently your code does not really try to accomplish what you describe. Copy&paste error? Your for loops just set `A` over and over - same for  `B` but only aftert all were done you do something regarding your dict. This line should be probably inside the dict somewhere....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempts rewrite the data at each iteration. Plus they lose the relation between the name and the index by only iterating on the values. Time to rethink the approach from *scratch*.

I would combine both dict data and build a new dictionary using dictionary comprehension:

```
result = {name:ages[index] for index,name in d1.items()}

>>> result
{'Bill': 20, 'Bob': 40, 'Callum': 20, 'Herrera': 21, 'Liz': 19}
```

note that `d1` is used just like a list of `tuples`. Only `ages` is used like a real dictionary. You can insert default ages to avoid key errors like this:

```
result = {name:ages.get(index,"unknown") for index,name in d1.items()}
```

so persons with missing index get a `"unknown"` age.

Comment: Thanks Jean-Francois Fabre!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply iterate over the names and do the following:

```
names = {
    0: "Callum",
    1: "Herrera",
    2: "Bob",
    3: "Bill",
    4: "Liz"
}

ages = {
    0: 20,
    1: 21,
    2: 40,
    3: 20,
    4: 19
}

name_age = {}
for key, value in names.items():
    name_age[value] = ages.get(key, -1)

>>> print(name_age)
{'Callum': 20, 'Bill': 20, 'Bob': 40, 'Liz': 19, 'Herrera': 21}
```

Although seems quite odd that you're using a `dict` as a `list`; if you'd like to mimic this behaviour using a `list` you can do so using `enumerate()` which will produce indexes accordingly.

The ideal scenario is to use a proper data structure as shown below; but it solely depends on your requirements.

```
name_age = [
    {
        "name": "Callum",
        "age": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "Herrera",
        "age": 21
    }
]
```